# Chainring offset - chainline - of Alfine vs. Ultegra/Dura Ace

Tags: shimano, chainring, crankset, belt-drive, chainline

I have a bike with Alfine 11 and belt drive. I think I could use a 175mm crank, certainly a 172.5, rather than the 170 Alfine comes in (height 6'1" frame size 60cm) and going a little lighter and prettier with Ultegra or Dura Ace appeals to me.

All are two-piece chainsets compatible with the Hollowtech II bottom bracket. All have 130 BCD. Seems like a straight swap is possible. The only thing I can thing of that might go wrong is belt alignment - is the offset of the larger chainring mounts on the road sets going to be the same as the mounts on the Alfine?

I was able to find that the quoted chainline for the Alfine chainset is 42.7mm - I can't find that figure for the other options.

new information: Gates produce a bunch of shims and spacers - mentioned in [the engineering manual](http://www.g-boxx.com/pdf/Gates-Shimano-manual-en.pdf) but I haven't been able to find them for sale anywhere. It looks like with this kit an Ultegra chainset will work but it's an expensive experiment without knowing for sure. I'll have to email Gates to try and find the kit, then buy the chain set if the rings look like they will correct the chainline - which from all information must be as perfect as possible.

Answer (score 2):

The Alfine has a chinaline of 42.7mm for a single crank and the Ultegra 43.5mm for the double and 45mm for the triple.

For the double the chainline is measured [halfway between the 2 rings](http://sheldonbrown.com/chainline.html#standards) so the outer ring will be even further out, but the inner further in.

Sheldon says "With typical 5 mm chainring spacing, this puts the inner at 41 mm, the outer at 46 mm".

1.7mm or 3.3mm both sound like a long way for a belt drive to me. But I'm not an expert there. You my be able to use the BB spacers to offset the whole crankset 1.7mm towards the drive side, but I'd rather not go down that route.

This is all assuming there's no extra molding on the cranks or rings to get in the way.